# jQuery FullCalendar startParam/endParam format

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

The format of of the fullcalendar startParam and endParam, doesn't seem to match their documentation.  The [doucumentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/startParam/) says it is an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) date format, but I'm pretty sure something bogus is going on.  This is what I see coming out of my browser connecting to my JSON feed:

```
  end  1407650400
start  1404021600
```

If this is ISO8601, I would guess the first two numbers are the year, the next two the month, then what is the rest?  It seems more like it is the unix timestamp, but the Unix timestamp is not ISO8601 as quoted in the documentation.

Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: to Mr Downvote: I'd like to hear how this is a bad question.  There is clearly a discrepancy between the full calendar documentation and the actual implementation of the code. While yes, I could have figured it out, then not told anyone, this would not help future users of FullCalendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 1.6.x the startParam and endParam is an UNIX timestamp, eg. 1407650400. In the newly released version 2.0.x this is changed to an ISO8601 date.

Please check if the version you are using and the documentation is the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the UNIX Timestamp ?

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.time.php

Answer (score 0):

It's the UNIX Time and defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

[image]